# Framework not found GoogleAppMeasurement (Flutter)

Tags: ios, flutter, admob

I am currently trying to compile my flutter application for iOS and keep getting the following error:

```
ld: framework not found GoogleAppMeasurement
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What I have tried:

1. `pod deintegrate` as well as deleting all relevant files and reinstalling.
2. Cleaning Derived Data
3. `flutter clean`
4. Making sure "Framework Search Paths" starts with `$(inherited)`
5. Upgrading cocoapods (`gem install cocoapods`)
6. Making sure my project is not stored on iCloud
7. Replacing all occurrences of `GoogleAppMeasurement` with `GoogleAppMeasurementWithoutAdIDSupport` in `Other Linker Flags`

I also get a warning while compiling `GoogleAppMeasurement` that I'm not sure is relevant:
[image: Compiler Warning]

Any help/workaround is appreciated, I mainly just need to get this to compile.

My `pubspec.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
  firebase_core: ^2.8.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.3.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.4.5
  firebase_crashlytics: ^3.0.17
  firebase_messaging: ^14.4.1
  google_mobile_ads: ^3.0.0
  google_sign_in: ^6.0.2
  flutter_facebook_auth: 4.0.1
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^5.0.17

  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```

And my `Podfile.lock`:

```
PODS:
...
  - AppAuth (1.6.2):
    - AppAuth/Core (= 1.6.2)
    - AppAuth/ExternalUserAgent (= 1.6.2)
  - AppAuth/Core (1.6.2)
  - AppAuth/ExternalUserAgent (1.6.2):
    - AppAuth/Core
  - cloud_firestore (4.7.1):
    - Firebase/Firestore (= 10.9.0)
    - firebase_core
    - Flutter
    - nanopb (< 2.30910.0, >= 2.30908.0)
  - FBAEMKit (12.2.1):
    - FBSDKCoreKit_Basics (= 12.2.1)
  - FBSDKCoreKit (12.2.1):
    - FBAEMKit (= 12.2.1)
    - FBSDKCoreKit_Basics (= 12.2.1)
  - FBSDKCoreKit_Basics (12.2.1)
  - FBSDKLoginKit (12.2.1):
    - FBSDKCoreKit (= 12.2.1)
  - Firebase/Auth (10.9.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAuth (~> 10.9.0)
  - Firebase/CoreOnly (10.9.0):
    - FirebaseCore (= 10.9.0)
  - Firebase/Crashlytics (10.9.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseCrashlytics (~> 10.9.0)
  - Firebase/DynamicLinks (10.9.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseDynamicLinks (~> 10.9.0)
  - Firebase/Firestore (10.9.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseFirestore (~> 10.9.0)
  - Firebase/Messaging (10.9.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseMessaging (~> 10.9.0)
  - firebase_auth (4.6.1):
    - Firebase/Auth (= 10.9.0)
    - firebase_core
    - Flutter
  - firebase_core (2.13.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly (= 10.9.0)
    - Flutter
  - firebase_crashlytics (3.3.1):
    - Firebase/Crashlytics (= 10.9.0)
    - firebase_core
    - Flutter
  - firebase_dynamic_links (5.3.1):
    - Firebase/DynamicLinks (= 10.9.0)
    - firebase_core
    - Flutter
  - firebase_messaging (14.6.1):
    - Firebase/Messaging (= 10.9.0)
    - firebase_core
    - Flutter
  - FirebaseAppCheckInterop (10.10.0)
  - FirebaseAuth (10.9.0):
    - FirebaseAppCheckInterop (~> 10.0)
    - FirebaseCore (~> 10.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.8)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.8)
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (< 4.0, >= 2.1)
  - FirebaseCore (10.9.0):
    - FirebaseCoreInternal (~> 10.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.8)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 7.8)
  - FirebaseCoreExtension (10.10.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 10.0)
  - FirebaseCoreInternal (10.10.0):
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 7.8)"
  - FirebaseCrashlytics (10.9.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 10.5)
    - FirebaseInstallations (~> 10.0)
    - FirebaseSessions (~> 10.5)
    - GoogleDataTransport (~> 9.2)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.8)
    - nanopb (< 2.30910.0, >= 2.30908.0)
    - PromisesObjC (~> 2.1)
  - FirebaseDynamicLinks (10.9.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 10.0)
  - FirebaseFirestore (10.9.0):
    - abseil/algorithm (~> 1.20211102.0)
    - abseil/base (~> 1.20211102.0)
    - abseil/container/flat_hash_map (~> 1.20211102.0)
    - abseil/memory (~> 1.20211102.0)
    - abseil/meta (~> 1.20211102.0)
    - abseil/strings/strings (~> 1.20211102.0)
    - abseil/time (~> 1.20211102.0)
    - abseil/types (~> 1.20211102.0)
    - FirebaseCore (~> 10.0)
    - "gRPC-C++ (~> 1.44.0)"
    - leveldb-library (~> 1.22)
    - nanopb (< 2.30910.0, >= 2.30908.0)
  - FirebaseInstallations (10.10.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 10.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.8)
    - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (~> 7.8)
    - PromisesObjC (~> 2.1)
  - FirebaseMessaging (10.9.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 10.0)
    - FirebaseInstallations (~> 10.0)
    - GoogleDataTransport (~> 9.2)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.8)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.8)
    - GoogleUtilities/Reachability (~> 7.8)
    - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (~> 7.8)
    - nanopb (< 2.30910.0, >= 2.30908.0)
  - FirebaseSessions (10.10.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 10.5)
    - FirebaseCoreExtension (~> 10.0)
    - FirebaseInstallations (~> 10.0)
    - GoogleDataTransport (~> 9.2)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.10)
    - nanopb (< 2.30910.0, >= 2.30908.0)
    - PromisesSwift (~> 2.1)
  - Flutter (1.0.0)
  - flutter_facebook_auth (3.5.3):
    - FBSDKCoreKit (~> 12.2.1)
    - FBSDKLoginKit (~> 12.2.1)
    - Flutter
  - flutter_local_notifications (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - flutter_secure_storage (6.0.0):
    - Flutter
  - flutter_web_auth (0.5.0):
    - Flutter
  - flutter_web_auth_2 (1.1.1):
    - Flutter
  - FMDB (2.7.5):
    - FMDB/standard (= 2.7.5)
  - FMDB/standard (2.7.5)
  - Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (10.4.0):
    - GoogleAppMeasurement (< 11.0, >= 7.0)
    - GoogleUserMessagingPlatform (>= 1.1)
  - google_mobile_ads (1.0.0):
    - Flutter
    - Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (~> 10.4.0)
    - webview_flutter_wkwebview
  - google_sign_in_ios (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
    - GoogleSignIn (~> 6.2)
  - GoogleAppMeasurement (10.10.0):
    - GoogleAppMeasurement/AdIdSupport (= 10.10.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.11)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 7.11)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 7.11)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 7.11)"
    - nanopb (< 2.30910.0, >= 2.30908.0)
  - GoogleAppMeasurement/AdIdSupport (10.10.0):
    - GoogleAppMeasurement/WithoutAdIdSupport (= 10.10.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.11)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 7.11)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 7.11)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 7.11)"
    - nanopb (< 2.30910.0, >= 2.30908.0)
  - GoogleAppMeasurement/WithoutAdIdSupport (10.10.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.11)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 7.11)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 7.11)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 7.11)"
    - nanopb (< 2.30910.0, >= 2.30908.0)
  - GoogleDataTransport (9.2.3):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.7)
    - nanopb (< 2.30910.0, >= 2.30908.0)
    - PromisesObjC (< 3.0, >= 1.2)
  - GoogleSignIn (6.2.4):
    - AppAuth (~> 1.5)
    - GTMAppAuth (~> 1.3)
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (< 3.0, >= 1.1)
  - GoogleUserMessagingPlatform (2.0.1)
  - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (7.11.1):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - GoogleUtilities/Network
  - GoogleUtilities/Environment (7.11.1):
    - PromisesObjC (< 3.0, >= 1.2)
  - GoogleUtilities/Logger (7.11.1):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
  - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (7.11.1):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GoogleUtilities/Network (7.11.1):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib"
    - GoogleUtilities/Reachability
  - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (7.11.1)"
  - GoogleUtilities/Reachability (7.11.1):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (7.11.1):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GTMAppAuth (1.3.1):
    - AppAuth/Core (~> 1.6)
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (< 3.0, >= 1.5)
  - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (2.3.0)
  - launch_review (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - leveldb-library (1.22.2)
  - path_provider_foundation (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
    - FlutterMacOS
  - PromisesObjC (2.2.0)
  - PromisesSwift (2.2.0):
    - PromisesObjC (= 2.2.0)
  - share_plus (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - shared_preferences_foundation (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
    - FlutterMacOS
  - sign_in_with_apple (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - sqflite (0.0.3):
    - Flutter
    - FMDB (>= 2.7.5)
  - url_launcher_ios (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - webview_flutter_wkwebview (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
```

`flutter doctor`:

```
[!] Flutter (Channel unknown, 3.7.12, on macOS 12.1 21C52 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
    ! Flutter version 3.7.12 on channel unknown at /Users/USER/development/flutter
      Currently on an unknown channel. Run `flutter channel` to switch to an official channel.
      If that doesnt fix the issue, reinstall Flutter by following instructions at
      https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install.
    ! Unknown upstream repository.
      Reinstall Flutter by following instructions at https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.4.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

Thanks!

Comment: did u manage to solve this ?